# Image processing automation - filter square images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, image-format

How does Photoshop treat a perfectly square image? Are they considered a Portrait or Landscape? I need to automate some image processing and I need to filter out perfectly square (aspect ratio 1:1) images for separate handling.

Comment: I don't know that it does differentiate either way. What's stopping you form just looking at the width/height and determining it that way?

Comment: My guess is that in PS it could be either (though technically both are wrong)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking how a program works, not about design

Comment: But it is a design question. I started thinking about this in regard to automation, but started wondering about why automation routines only allow 2 choices: landscape or portrait. I agree that perfectly square images should be in a third category.

Comment: Because squares work the same regardless of setting. So a square is both landscape and portrait at the same time.